# Do I need additional power for an IR LED diode 50 feet away from a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: circuit-design, infrared, led-driver

I'm creating a central remote to control my mini-split HVAC units. Those units are controlled with an IR remote. Each unit is in a different room of my house.

I have everything working on my breadboard and the IR LEDs are able to control the HVAC when it's in the same room.

However, the Pi will be in my server room and each of the IR LEDs will be wired to a different room in my house. The rooms are anywhere from 30 to 50 feet (10-15m) away from server room.

The unit will have multiple LEDs but only one LED will be sending a signal at a given time.

[I'm using these IR LEDs from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XYNDRGF).

```
RX IR LED
Working Voltage : 2.7 - 5.5V
Working Current : 0.6 - 0.8mA
Carrier Freq.   : 38KHz
BMP width       : 8KHz
Receiving Angle : 70°
Receiving Dist. : 15m

TX IR LED 
Working Voltage : 0.9 - 1.3V
Reverse Voltage : 5V
Forward DC      : 30mA
Launch Angle    : 30°
Emission Dist.  : 12 - 13m
```

What gauge wire should I use to connect the LEDs over that distance?

Will the 3v power from the Pi be enough to power the LEDs that far away?

If I need to use an additional power source to power the LEDs, what would that schematic look like?

Note: I'm hard wiring this for reliability and simplicity. I don't want to create multiple wireless WiFi modules that communicate with the Pi. I just want the diode in the other rooms.

Here's my schematic

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Definitely do not use the pi's 3v3 rail as that is very delicate.  Drop at 5v over that distance might be reasonable but with wires that long you probably want something to protect the pi from induced surges.  You'd probably want a driver for the LED anyway...  Needless to say your schematic makes no sense whatsoever - that is *not* how a transistor is used.

Comment: Have you considered wireless solutions like cheap 433Mhz/315Mhz/900Mhz transmitters? Just a though to save the time running wires.

Comment: 15m distance are 30mA is ideal line of site only with no wall reflections of people walking down hallway and reflections attenuate.  Either run phone wire with remote LEDS and the right transistor design or use mirrors , Heatshrink tubes, and line of site with 100 mA peak currents.  Then use all emitters in an array off 5 or 12V for more power and software MUX on 1 port out

Comment: The LEDs 'datasheets' are on the amazon webpage on the bottom in a picture :)

Comment: @ChrisStratton - I followed the design on this page http://www.piddlerintheroot.com/ir-blaster-lirc/ It was explained that the transistor was helping the LED switch on/off faster which would transmit a clearer IR code. I'm knew to electronics. Is the transistor not helpful with fast switching?

Comment: @MadHatter - I'm avoiding wireless because that would create a lot more complexity and lowers reliability. I don't want these things losing connection in the middle of the night. Also, they'd each need line-of-site positioning, so nothing can block them. With wired, I can snake the wires along the existing mini-split piping and place the within the mini-split housing. The IR LED will be directly beside the receiver without concern for anything blocking it.

Comment: @Ephemeral - Thanks for catching that, for editing the question, and for all your other help! This is actually the second set of LEDs that I bought, so I didn't notice the datasheet on this set.

Comment: @MichaelKhalili the way you have drawn the transistor is completely and entirely wrong.  It will accomplish nothing at all.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - You're right. Each LED needs its own transistor with an LED & resistor connected to the emitter side, right?

(I'm just learning electronics and schematic drawing. Asking this question, reviewing the answers, and other drawings has improved my understanding dramatically. I appreciate every's feedback.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As earlier answer mentioned, yes its doable but I would not recommend it. Raspberry PI I/Os are pretty delicate and with a few additional components you could create a solid solution.

The way you are using an NPN transistor doesnt seem to be right. I would suggest you use FET/Transistor to mimize the current you draw from the 3.3V rail. Additionally since the amount of current the LED would consume is unknown, you certainly require a higher voltage power supply and not 3.3V. (Depending on what you can find easily, Your options could be any power supply with more then 5V output, e.g a 12V adapter, 19V laptop adapter etc). The ground between this power source and your Raspberry would have to be common. For each LED, your circuit would look something like below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXacAQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For any given AWG wire, the website below provide a decent table to estimate its resistance per 1000 ft and you could use that to estimate the cable resistance.

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Tables/wirega.html

Now addressing the cable selection, as your current is expected to be small, typically between 50mA to 200mA depending on the LED requirement, you could easily use a AWG 28 or so cable. Possibly a simple Ethernet cable as most ethernet cables are AWG24 to AWG28 rated (and usually sturdy, easily available and low cost). by playing around the R1 value, you could actually extend the length even further easily.

Comment: Right in concept, completely wrong in details.  While it's important to not use the pi's 3v3 rail, it makes no sense at all to use a 12v supply!   That would only be appropriate if there were a string of many LEDs in series.

Comment: I don't have a 12v supply handy. Could I use that BC547b for a 5v 0.5a power supply? I'm starting to understand my design flaws. Thanks for helping!

Comment: While there are no details available for the operating current of the LED, its a bit difficult to say what would be the voltage drop across the long wires. You could use any Standard adapters of 5V or 12V or higher voltage laptop charges(~19V), technically you could use any one of them depending on which one you could find easily. If your LEDs were to consume more then 200mA of current each you would certainly want to go for a power supply above 5V.

Answer (score 1):

`TX IR LED 
Working Voltage : 0.9 - 1.3V
Reverse Voltage : 5V
Forward DC      : 30mA`

You can drive an IR LED with higher current pulses (more than 30mA) as long as the maximum average current spec is not exceeded.

If you power the LED from 3.3V using a BJT (0.1V Vcesat) and a resistor to limit current, there will be 0.9-1.3V on the LED, and 1.6V minimum on the resistor. This is enough voltage drop to control LED current properly. For 30mA that would be a 56 ohms resistor.

Let's try 25AWG telephone cable. That's about 650 ohms/km. Two 20ft wires make 60ft so about 20m or about 13 ohms. At 30mA current that's 0.39V, it is okay. You can also measure cable resistance with a multimeter.

If you want to overdo it, you can substract cable resistance from the resistor value, so yor 56 ohms would end up at say 47 ohms. But you don't have to, if the LED is aimed at the receiver, even from the other end of the room, it will probably work even with much less current than 30mA.

Schematic:

[image]

Use any NPN BJT that will take the current, like BC337 or 2N2904. 1k base resistor gives 2.7mA base current, that'll be plenty to saturate the transistor. R5 value should be 47-56 ohms, and VCC should be 3.3V from your Pi. You can use 5V too if you have a 5V supply in your device already, this should be the case if the Pi is powered from a USB "charger". In that case increase the value of R5 to (5-Vled-Vcesat)/30mA = about 100-120 ohms.

Note the resistor is best placed on the transistor side, not at the other end of the cable with the LED. This will protect the transistor if the two wires get shorted.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the site Michael.

If you are only powering 1 LED over ~15 meters, I'm assuming your LEDs are around 20mA max and require maximum of 2V.

You should be fine powering them off the 3.3V rail (mind it has a 50mA maximum current limit). Using just about any 2 conductor wire from 18-28 AWG. You should use some sort of relay or transistor instead of driving directly from the IO pin though since the IO pins are only allowed to source 16mA of current. You also could power them off the 5V rail as well, you will just need a larger value resistor.

**Worst Case Calculation:**
Driving the LED with 20mA on 15m of 28 AWG wire (round trip 30m) you lose 130mV, which is insignificant.

Comment: So people stop down voting me... This answer was created before he updated with his specific parts etc...